# parcel build error: "extendDefaultPlugins"

Tags: parceljs

i'm trying to build project of mine.

I new to using parcel. To build process i have this command line

```
"build": "parcel build index.html --dist-dir ./dist"
```

I get this error.

```
console: 
"extendDefaultPlugins" utility is deprecated.
Use "preset-default" plugin with overrides instead.
For example:
{
  name: 'preset-default',
  params: {
    overrides: {
      // customize plugin options
      convertShapeToPath: {
        convertArcs: true
      },
      // disable plugins
      convertPathData: false
    }
  }
}

√ Built in 4.24s

dist\index.html                3.74 KB    879ms
dist\favicon.9a1bb8f5.png      13.3 KB     24ms
dist\logo.9272a069.png        92.31 KB     49ms
dist\icons.9801e6f1.svg        8.81 KB    871ms
dist\index.20fbdb0c.css        9.96 KB    2.00s
dist\index.4a83a35e.js       125.64 KB    1.68s
dist\icons.9801e6f1.svg        8.81 KB    871ms
[Error: Error opening directory]
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! forkify@1.0.0 build: `parcel build index.html --dist-dir ./dist`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the forkify@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

I can't find a solution.

Please help me.

Comment: According to the deprecation warning: I found this issue in the parcel bundler project: https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/6744. This warning seems unrelated to the error. To dig deeper, we will need further details.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is a warning coming from svgo (module to optimize svg files). It probably means Parcel updated the version, but not the configuration. According to the github issue, it is already fixed but not published yet. Be patient, the warning will probably go away is a new version. Ignore it for now.

Answer (score 1):

This was [an issue in parcel `2.0.0-rc.0`](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/6744), that is [fixed](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/pull/6785) in the now-released version `2.0.0`.

It had no functional impact - it was just a warning that the way in which the `@parcel/optimizer-htmlnano` configured `svgo` should eventually [be updated to use a new technique](https://github.com/svg/svgo/pull/1513).